# OneLogin programmatic session cookie validation - No browser

Tags: session, single-sign-on, session-cookies, onelogin

I have the following scenario that I am curious if it is possible to implement. I need to use SSO and more specifically OneLogin to authenticate the user via custom UI from my Java standalone application. I know this can be done via [Create Session Login Token](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token) and then [Create session via token](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-via-token) One Login API calls. With some parsing I can get the session cookie out of the last call and store it.

Now I need to programmatically hit the API server, which is to be build still and this server somehow needs to validate the session cookie that I am going to send along with request. The key word "Programatically" as in there will be no browser

OneLogin doesn't provide SDK to validate existing session cookie => it would be nice if I could, based on session cookie find out if it is still valid and what is the user name used for this session. If session is invalid API server would return unauthorized.

Is this even possible? Or is it possible in some other way?

1. Basically One Login is already used in our ecosystem and I have to continue using it
2. The app that will log user in and get the session cookie may not be the one calling the API server.  This  could be another java application that would receive the session

I guess what I am looking for is [Validate Session](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/validate-session) equivalent from Open ID Connect API in general API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `session_token` that is returned via that API has a short expiry is only intended to be used for making the Create Session request which returns session cookies.

It sounds like OpenId Connect might be the best option for this use case. If you have user credentials then you could use the [Resource Owner Password Grant flow](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/password-grant) to authenticate the user and obtain an `id_token`.

The `id_token` is a JWT containing user details can then be verified for authenticity by checking its signature, audience and expiry claims. It can also hold other custom information about the user that may be used by your backend application.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your comment. Looks like the link you have provided is to v2 of OIDC Connect API that is not publicly available. Can you confirmed that v1 returns JWT token as well in access_token result set: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token

Comment: => I suspect that it is. Is there a key you can use to decode JWT from OneLogin?

Comment: Or are you suppose to use https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token/introspection with access_token from password grant to get sub (which is the Open Login user id) and then if it is active token use Get User By ID call to retrieve the user information. It would be much easier if we could decode the this information from JWT but v1 access_token may not be JWT (missing three distinct groups)

Comment: The v1 Access Token is not a JWT. The ID Token is a JWT and contains the unique user Id in `sub` claim. 

v2 is on preview release but will be promoted to GA next week (starting Jan 6th 2020). It will take a couple of days for the release to complete and will be ready later in the week. 

v2 has JWT Access Tokens and also includes the ID Token with the Password Grant. 

The introspection endpoint on both versions requires the use of an Access Token to make the request.

Comment: Most OIDC client libraries will take care of JWT validation for you using the JWKs endpoint to verify the signature. You should also verify the the iss, aud and exp are valid.